# Changing headings to numbered headings in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I wrote a document in Word (Office 2010), with 3 levels of headings. I didn't bother with the numbering (ie 1.1 and 1.2 etc).

I went to have a cup of tea, and had a think about it, and thought 'what the hey' I think I WILL have numbering in my headings after all. The only problem is that my document is really long with many headings. Do I have to go through all the headings and add numbers manually or is there an automatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on each your styles in the Quick style gallery and modify it so it includes numbering. The whole document should be updated with numbering automatically.

Comment: This results in chapter 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.4, 2.5 whereas it should be 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2,

Comment: Figured it out. Added answer

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions shown in the pictures here:

[image]

[image]